# How do i set the borders of an mplot3d, and also make the grid lines lie behind the plot?

Tags: matplotlib, mplot3d

I have this plot as part of a PySide program;

[image]

And there are two problems I have with it. The first is the ugly grey border. I know I can can get rid of it using the toolbar option, but I can't find a way to it programatically, or make it default to that when it plots...

The second issue, is that it is drawing the grid lines on top of the surface, which I would rather it didn't do... How do I get the grid lines to be drawn underneath the surface?

EDIT:

i'm using version 1.1.1;

this doesn't happen for all plot types - i.e.

[image]

that is fine.

If i try and plot multiple objects, then it can be a problem;

[image]

but i understand that's a limitation of mplot3d not being a try 3D engine, just a set of 3D images with a *Z-Ordering*, so the order of objects drawn becomes orientation dependant. (same graph - different angle: [enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gEkh.jpg)).

The grid lines should surely always be at the bottom of the drawing though, no? Is there a way to force them to be?

Will.

Comment: Which version of matplotlib are you using? The lines shouldn't be in front.... As far as the gray background, you can set it with `fig.set_facecolor('white')` (or the string `'none'` if you want it to be the same as the rest of the background).

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?  I have the same problem.

Comment: gridline issue for me is discussed here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/750